# How to find the code behind in Apex

Tags: salesforce, apex

I'm new to Salesforce / Apex

There is this guy worked on our salesforce and he left me with many code. My questions, we have a little problem with some of the fields on one of the application form. How do I find where is the code behind this application? Thanks.

Comment: Please specify what "Apex" is and how you are using it.

Comment: I am late to the party, but I have found the Search feature in eclipse force.com Ide to be very useful. It will search across classes and in almost all cases, it will find the correct file.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways in which Apex can be added to perform custom logic in your salesforce application, there's no clear answer which is doing what and you'll need to dig in to discover that if nothing has been documented in your organization.

- Check if any triggers exist
- Verify if any apex jobs are scheduled, they can be performing apex batches executign logic
- verify if your application page are default page layouts or whether they have inline Visualforce elements or are a full Visualforce page. Anything Visualforce is most likely backed up by apex controllers performing business logic.

Beyond Apex, have you checked if there are any configured workflows which are performing field updates ? These too can modify data.